# Html5 video clip in reverse

Tags: jquery, arrays, html, html5-video

I want to reverse html5 video clip of particular range in reverse. For normal play it work with below code.

```
function playVideoTeaserFrom (startTime, endTime) {
       var videoplayer = document.getElementById("yourVideoplayer");  //get your videoplayer

       videoplayer.currentTime = starttime; //not sure if player seeks to seconds or milliseconds
       videoplayer.play();

       //call function to stop player after given intervall
       var stopVideoAfter = (endTime - startTime) * 1000;  //* 1000, because Timer is in ms
       setTimeout(function(){
           videoplayer.stop();
       }, stopVideoAfter);

   }
```

if we use

```
video.playbackRate = 1.0; 
video.currentTime += -.1;
```

video jump in sections and end to default starting value not at particular range

Answer (score 4):

Set a negative playbackRate:

```
video.playbackRate = -1.0;
```

**EDIT** As I just found out, this only works with Safari.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/WebAudio_playbackRate_explained) says:

> Most browsers stop playing audio outside playbackRate bounds of 0.5 and 4, leaving the video playing silently. It's therefore recommended for most applications that you limit the range to between 0.5 and 4.

I found out that this in fact seems to be like that in Firefox and Chrome. Firefox even reports an error message when I try to set a negative `playbackRate`:

> [Exception... "Method not implemented"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code ::  :: line 1"  data: no]

So, I recommend reverse the video in an external tool and replace the source of the video. To make it more or less seamless, it should be possible to pre-load it in the background.